# Css selector - which one to prefer when classes with space?

Tags: css, css-selectors

When selecting phone number using css selector, I got stuck coming across a class with space among them. With at least ten selectors I can achieve my target. My question is which one I should prefer and why? Thanks in advance.

Elements within which the class lies:

```
<div itemprop="telephone" class="phones phone primary">(310) 443-8911</div>
```

Selectors I've talked above:

```
div.phones
div .phones 
div.phones.phone
div .phones.phone    
div.phone.primary
div .phone.primary   
div.primary
div .primary  
div.phones.phone.primary
div .phones.phone.primary
```

Comment: These selectors are **not all the same** and reflect different structures and selections.

Comment: You can read up on selectors here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A space between classes indicates separate class names, not a single name. For example, `class="phones phone primary"` means that the element has three classes: phones, phone, and primary.

You can select this element using any of these classes. For example:

```
div.phones
div.phones.phone
div.phone.primary
div.primary
div.phones.phone.primary
```

However the following will NOT work:

```
div .phones 
div .phones.phone    
div .phone.primary   
div .primary  
div .phones.phone.primary
```

to select the element `<div itemprop="telephone" class="phones phone primary">(310) 443-8911</div>` (unless it also happens to be a descendant of another div) because the space between `div` and the class(es) listed indicates a descendant relationship. In other words, introducing a space means select an element with the listed classes (e.g. `.phones.phone`) that is a descendant of a div.

In terms of which one of the valid selector you should use is entirely up to you and your needs. The first group above is all valid in terms of selecting what you want, but their [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) with respect to other selectors and other rules you have can factor into how they're rendered.

Comment: Thanks j08691, for your answer. The problem is I've got it working with all the selectors I've mentioned above. That means what you said in the above description listing 5 selectors that those will not work is different in my case. I've got all the above mentioned 10 selectors working. I just double checked. Thanks.

Comment: It's working because you have the div you showed in your question as a descendant of *another* div (not shown in your question) as I noted in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I went through your answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Which to prefer is based in what you're trying to achieve. Others have indicated that the space separates each class. You can use a combination of classes in your CSS to share styles among elements while also targeting specific ones.

For example, if you had HTML that looked like:

```
<div itemprop="telephone" class="phone primary">Phone: (310) 443-8911</div>
<div itemprop="telephone" class="phone">Cell: (310) 443-1234</div>
<div itemprop="telephone" class="phone">Fax: (310) 443-4321</div>
```

You might want to style all phone numbers similarly, with some variation:

```
/* For all phone numbers */
div.phone {
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 18px;
     cursor: default;
     display: block;
     color: black;
}

/* Just the primary phone */
div.phone.primary {
     color: red;
}
```

This way, the primary phone number can look like every other phone number except it's red instead of black.

Your element having the classes "phones" and "phone" seems unnecessary to me though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a class with spaces, this is a div with three classes.

As for your selectors, once you understand how the different parts work together, it becomes easy

- `div` is an element type selector, it only matches elements whose html type is `div`
- `.xyz` is a class selector, it only matches elements who have `xyz` as one of their classes (they will still match if they also have other classes in addition to `xyz`)
- if you glue two selectors together like this `div.xyz`, the selector will only match elements that match both parts, so this one will match only divs that have at least `xyz` as a class (and it’s okay if they have other classes)
- you can also glue together two class selectors, etc. For instance, `div.abc.xyz` will only match `div`s that have both class `abc` and `xyz`
- if you put a space between two selectors, you get a descendant selector. For instance `div .xyz` will match elements that have `xyz` as one of their classes, and that are either children, or grandchildren, or yet more distant descendants of a div. The selector will match, for instance, the `h1` in `<div><h1 class='xyz'>bla</h1></div>`, but it won’t match `<div class='xyz'>bla</div>` sitting at the root of the document (because it isn’t a descendant of a `div`)

Among the selectors you listed, the following ones are guaranteed to match your element:

- `div.phones`
- `div.phones.phone`
- `div.phone.primary`
- `div.primary`
- `div.phones.phone.primary`

The following selectors will only match your element if it is, directly or indirectly, inside another div

- `div .phones`
- `div .phones.phone`
- `div .phone.primary`
- `div .primary`
- `div .phones.phone.primary`

Which selector you use depends on how specific you want to be, that is, which other elements of your page you want to match or not. For instance, `div.phones.phone.primary` is more specific than `div.phones`, meaning, it will potentially match fewer other elements in your page.

If you want to read about specific disciplines for systematically choosing your selectors and classes, you should read about OOCSS, Atomic CSS, BEM, and friends. You could read [this article](http://clubmate.fi/oocss-acss-bem-smacss-what-are-they-what-should-i-use/) to get started.

Comment: Thanks Zen for your answer. However, I went through your elaborative answer and I could find it informative. Anyways, gonna fix it no matter whoever downvoted.